# Web page crawling by Google for SEO

Tags: seo, web-crawlers

On Our website we have an angular component which have multiple tabs and loads all the data (of all the tabs) at once.
As per our new requirement to increase the 1st load speed, we will be loading only first 3 data from 1st tab on initial load and on click of load more button or other tabs subsequent and corresponding data will be loaded.

For us SEO and Data Crawl by the search engine is very very important and we can't compromise on that.

My Concern/Question is how search engine would crawl data, let say, if 8th tab is never clicked and data is never loaded to the page. We can't even specifically provide the tab's data to search engine as we have millions of different id's and hence different result(data) for the tabs, so that will be real tough.

Comment: Angular and tabs are poor choices when you want good SEO.   I'd recommend ditching those components and redesigning your website.

Comment: I can't redesign the website now so as immediate solution could you please tell me if certain data is not loaded to page will Google be able to crawl it?